# Angular 2 Kendo UI autocomplete not working for numbers

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an autocomplete field

```
<kendo-autocomplete
          [data]="postCodes"
          [placeholder]="'Search for a PostCode'"
          [suggest]="true"
          (valueChange)="valueChange($event)"
          [(ngModel)]="hospital"
        >

        </kendo-autocomplete>
```

The autocomplete works fine for array of Strings. 
I am trying to achieve autocomplete for Postcode. Even though I declare it as an array of string, it does not seem to make a difference.

I am getting the following error when I select the value in the autocomplete

```
AutoCompleteComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: this.suggestedText.toLowerCase is not a function
    at AutoCompleteComponent.get [as suggestion] (autocomplete.component.js:160)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AutoCompleteComponent.html:7)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (
```

I have done a lot of digging and I cannot seem to get the correct answer to this. I even tried modifying the Number.prototype.toLowerCase as mentioned in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890859/kendo-autocomplete-on-numeric-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the list items the AutoComplete is bound to are actual strings, the component seems to be working as expected:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: ['.countries { width: 300px; }'],
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <kendo-autocomplete
          [data]="postCodes"
          [placeholder]="'Search for a PostCode'"
          [suggest]="true"
          [(value)]="zipCode"
        >

        </kendo-autocomplete>
        <hr />
        <pre>Selected code: {{zipCode}}</pre>
    </div>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public postCodes: Array<string> = [
     "1234",
     "2345",
     "9999"
     ];

     public zipCode = '';
}
```

[WORKING](http://plnkr.co/edit/wYX7OTbixr747gl9gqpw?p=preview)

... while the described error occurs only when the items are numbers:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: ['.countries { width: 300px; }'],
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <kendo-autocomplete
          [data]="postCodes"
          [placeholder]="'Search for a PostCode'"
          [suggest]="true"
          [(value)]="zipCode"
        >

        </kendo-autocomplete>
        <hr />
        <pre>Selected code: {{zipCode}}</pre>
    </div>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public postCodes: Array<string> = [
     1234,
     2345,
     9999
     ];

     public zipCode;
}
```

[NOT WORKING/ERROR](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPEVno1aWWtSpvmeT7Us?p=preview)

Make sure that the model value the AutoComplete is bound to via ngModel is of type string, as well as that the list items are strings as well.

If the issue persists, it would be helpful to share a similar runnable example, where the error can be observed.

Comment: Thank you. I had to explicitly cast it to be a string  even though the target array was declared as Type Array<String>